# Is there any difference between 'to affiliate with' and 'to affiliate to'?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, sentence

When I was looking up the word '***affiliate***', the dictionary offered the example sentences which I've been really confused from.

---

The actual meaning of the word 'affiliate' is

- *to cause a group **to become part of** OR **form a close relationship with another**, usually larger, group, or oganization*.

Now, which sentence applies to which meaning?

1. A ​college affiliated **to** the University of Mumbai.
2. The ​school is affiliated **with** a ​national ​association of ​driving
   schools.

I assume that the first sentence means that 2 schools have associated so now, they work as a whole and the second one refers to the fact, that these 2 companies have just a good relationship that helps them to be both more profitable. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think your distinction has any justification whatsoever. *Affiliation* is invariably a relatively "formal" process, and the fact that [**with** is used far more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affiliated+to%2Caffiliated+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20with%3B%2Cc0) is just a matter of established idiomatic preference, nothing to do with any supposed difference in meaning.

Comment: After viewing [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affiliated+with%2Caffiliated+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20to%3B%2Cc0), it appears "to" is British and "with" is American.  Before seeing the data, I, an American, would have said that "to" is simply wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The data come from The Cambridge Dictionary where is nothing mentioned about the differences.

Comment: In general, "affiliate with" suggests an equal relationship, while "affiliate to" a subordination. So the frequency of either phrase may also depend on the frequency of various kinds of affiliations in either geography.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between affiliate to and affiliate with. Both prepositions can be used indifferently. I've seen "affiliate to" in relating two colleges or a college to a university. However,  affiliate with is more common and used predominantly.